Old horror movie with living puppets and a "drill hat"
I'm looking for an old horror movie for which I haven't so much details (I've seen it maybe 20 years ago) but there is a particular scene which could help.
A couple is playing on their bed. One of them has a blindfold (and, maybe,  is also tied to the bed). Suddenly, their door opens and we can see one or two little living puppet. One is going under the bed. The person on the bed which is not tied looks under the bed and see the puppet (which have a hat shaped like a drill). The "drill hat" begins to start and hurry to the person's face (no explicit image is seen here I think). After that, the tied person ask what is going on and we can see at this moment the tongue (I frankly think it is) of the other person which begin to go out of the mouth.
